# "Shell connection" item disappeared from Midnight Commander menu

Tags: ssh, opensuse, upgrade, remote, mc

I have performed an upgrade of my OS (openSUSE 13.1 -> 13.2) and now no longer see menu item in Midnight Commander that allows me to perform operations with remote files via SSH. Coressponding menu item just disappered. What may be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely, mc was built without fish/shell link support. a bugreport about that happening in 13.1 is here : https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=911286

there should be SFTP entry in the menu. while similar, it does not use ssh keys in mc, thus you might want to comment on the opensuse bugreport saying that 13.2 suffers from the same problem.

edit : apparently, this is an intentional change as vfs/fish could lose your files in some cases. see http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse/2014-12/msg01128.html for more detail